# WebGL performance drop in recent Chrome releases

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

im not sure why (probably an update) but chrome has significantly lost performance while running some things I've made with three.js. I haven't worked on anything in a month and now that i've returned to my project i've found things are suddenly running much slower than they used to. I used to get a smooth 60 fps+, and now things are chugging along at 20 fps in one of my programs.

Just to be clear, I've changed absolutely nothing. I simply opened my projects a month later and the performance has dropped by 40+ fps, which is frightening. This is true for anything using three.js.

I'm wondering if anyone knows what the issue is.

EDIT:

http://gamejolt.com/games/arcade/tiny-tank/27522/

This is an application I've made which has significantly degraded in performance, at least on my machine. There also strange shading behavior which has appeared on the shading of certain objects due to hidden lights(?).

I'm using the WebGL renderer by the way.

I'm using Three.js version r66, since there are no migration instructions to move to any higher versions on github.

Comment: I have no problems with Chrome, happily handles most things at 60fps. But anyway, unless you can narrow it down to a programming question with some code for people to look at, this doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: More facts are needed for this to be a question. Please 1) publish you benchmark code 2) test it with different Chrome versions and show how it degrades http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php

Comment: I've linked to something which is suffering the performance decrease. Again the problem doesn't seem to be the code, i haven't changed anything in all of my applications, they're just suddenly running much slower and i can't understand why. I'll get on trying to test it with different versions to give a good example, but none on the site you've linked seem recent enough to be the cause (the change occurred some time in late june-july)

Comment: +1 simply because I've noticed a similar apparent drop in performance

Comment: Stackoverflow is the wrong place to complain about this. Try http://crbug.com

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful in any way, but Tiny Tank runs absolutely fine for me at 58-60fps 2560x1440 with max detail in Chrome 36.0.1985.125 on a GTX 770 2GB. It must be something related to your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) and make sure `Override software rendering list` is set to `enabled`. This will make sure the GPU-acceleration is enabled on unsupported system configurations